# Help to sum these two series $\sin(x)-\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)...$

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, trigonometric-series

I am reading Euler's paper entitled "Subsidium Calculi Sinuum" and he wrote down some "sums" for these trigonometric series:

\begin{align}S &= \sin(x)-\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)-\sin(4x)...\\\\
C &= \cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)-\cos(4x)...\\\\
-1+C &= -1+\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)-\cos(4x)...\\\\
-1+C+iS&=-1+[\cos(x)+\sin(x)]-[\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)+[\cos(3x)+\sin(3x)]-[\cos(4x)+\sin(4x)]...\end{align}

$$-1+e^{ix}-(e^{ix})^2+(e^{ix})^3-(e^{ix})^4+...$$

This is the geometric series, and I recognise that its "sum" is $-\dfrac{1}{1+e^{ix}}$

So, we have:

\begin{align}
& -\frac{1}{1+e^{ix}}=-\frac{1+e^{-ix}}{(1+e^{ix})(1+e^{-ix})} \\[8pt]
= {} & -\frac{1+\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}{(1+e^{ix})(1+e^{-ix})}=-\frac{1+\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}{2\cos(x)+2}
\end{align}

Equating the real and imaginary part with $C+iS$, we have:

$$-1+C=-\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2+\cos(2x)}\implies C=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$S=-\frac{\sin(x)}{2\cos(x)+2}$$

However, for the sum of $S$, there shouldn't be a minus sign, according to Euler.

So what is wrong with my derivation?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:
$$
f(x)=\color{red}-\frac{1+\cos(x)\color{red}-i\sin(x)}{2\cos(x)+2}\implies
S=\Im f(x)=\color{red}+\frac{\sin(x)}{2\cos(x)+2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your numerator should be $1+e^{-ix}$, not $1+e^{ix}$.

Comment: Ok, fixed, just a typo

Comment: @JamesWarthington You need to change one more sign, namely the one you've asked about.